# Android Interaction - Music

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an Android app that contains a String with numbers between 1 and 6 (e.g 165231543214).

I need my app to look through each char of the string and depending on the number, play a 1 second clip from a .wav file. (This I can manage)

However whenever code comes across the number 2, I require the app to wait for the user to press the screen (or a button) before the .wav file is played, and then carry on playing other .wav files until it comes across a number 2 again or runs out of numbers to play.

I just started out with Android a couple of weeks ago and have read into Services and asynkTasks but I am unsure how to proceed exactly.

Any guidance would be great!

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
String song = {"path to sound for 1","path to sound for 2"and so on..}
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
int i=0;
//initialise playButton
playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v){ //implement onClick to play first sound
 playSong((Integer.parseInt(str.charAt(i++)))-1);

 }
}

playSong(int songIndex){
   mediaPlayer.reset();
   try{

   mediaPlayer.setDataSource(song[songIndex]);
   mediaPlayer.prepare();
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
   mediaPlayer.start();

}
```